# How to get AcroField Properties using iText?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am using iText to read a pdf file. I have 20 Acro text fields in my pdf with different fillColor properties. I tried to read the properties but could not able to read. Is there any way we can get the fields which have a particular color as their fillcolor property in java?

**EDIT:**
I created acro fields in the pdf using the following Adobe Javascript

```
   var oFld = this.addField("nameOfField", "button", 0, fldRect);
    if (oFld != null) {
        oFld.buttonSetCaption("");
        oFld.borderStyle = border.s;
        oFld.fillColor = color.gray;
        oFld.textColor = color.white;
        oFld.lineWidth = 1;
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

now I am able to read the color properties.

Am not sure whether it is the right way to do it or not?

```
  if(dict.getAsDict(PdfName.MK).get(PdfName.BG) !=null){
            if(dict.getAsDict(PdfName.MK).get(PdfName.BG).toString().trim().equals("     
    [0.0, 1.0, 0.0]")){
                System.out.println(entry.getKey());
                System.out.println("Green");
            }
            if(dict.getAsDict(PdfName.MK).get(PdfName.BG).toString().trim().equals("
        [1.0, 0.0, 0.0]")){
                System.out.println(entry.getKey());
                System.out.println("Red");
            }

        }
```

Comment: Please provide the PDF in question. Just to make sure, that Javascript has been applied to the PDF *before* iText handels it, and you do not expect iText to execute the Javascript, do you?

Comment: *the right way to do it or not* - well, checking with string comparisons is **not** the right way. Those are numbers and should be checked as numbers. Furthermore your initial `if` clause `if(dict.getAsDict(PdfName.MK).get(PdfName.BG) !=null)` fails in the absence of an **MK** dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, if(ict.getAsDict(PdfName.MK)!=null) should avoid that null pointer exception and about the comparison, Should I iterate through  [1.0, 0.0, 0.0] and compare each number or how can I do the number comparison? @mkl

Comment: The value of `PdfName.BG` is a (direct or indirect) array. Thus, get it as an array. Then you can iterate. Keep in mind, though, that the number of array elements may differ. @Bruno's answer contains the relevant information.

Comment: @mkl I am using the following code to compare colors. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20193997/converting-rgb-values-into-color

Comment: The code there nowhere mentions string comparisons.

Comment: I pass the RGB values of array to the method then it returns the color name as string.

Comment: But BG does not necessarily contain RGB values. CMYK might also be in there. Or Grayscale.

Comment: As per my requirement I get only red or green

Comment: In that case you may succeed with that code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Chapter 8](http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=8) of my book discusses AcroForm fields from a rather high level. If you want to dig deeper, you need [chapter 13](http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=13). On page 449, table 13.11 lists the different `AcroFields.Item` methods. As you know a form field is described using a form dictionary. The visual representation(s) of a field is (or are) described using one or more widget annotations. You're looking for a property of the appearance, so you need the annotation dictionary.

You also know that the field dictionary and the widget dictionary are often merged when one field corresponds with one widget annotation, and that's why the `AcroFields.Item` class has a method called `getMerged()`. For every widget annotation of a specific field, it returns the merged properties of the field and the widget annotation.

That's the theory. Let's look at an example: [InspectForm](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=237)

```
Map<String,AcroFields.Item> fields = form.getFields();
AcroFields.Item item;
PdfDictionary dict;
int flags;
for (Map.Entry<String,AcroFields.Item> entry : fields.entrySet()) {
    out.write(entry.getKey());
    item = entry.getValue();
    dict = item.getMerged(0);
    // inspect dict
}
```

In the example, we inspect the field flags (`/FF`), which are properties of the field dictionary. You are interested in appearance characteristics, so I guess you'll want to inspect the `/MK` entry, which is (ISO-32000-1 Table 188):

> An appearance characteristics dictionary (see Table 189) that shall be
> used in constructing a dynamic appearance stream specifying the
> annotation’s visual presentation on the page. The name MK for this
> entry is of historical significance only and has no direct meaning.

You'll need to look at table 189 to find out the specific attributes you want:

> **R** *integer (Optional):* The number of degrees by which the widget
> annotation shall be rotated counterclockwise relative to the page. The
> value shall be a multiple of 90. Default value: 0.
>
> **BC** *array (Optional):*
> An array of numbers that shall be in the range 0.0 to 1.0 specifying
> the colour of the widget annotation’s border. The number of array
> elements determines the colour space in which the colour shall
> be defined: 0 No colour; transparent 1 DeviceGray 3 DeviceRGB 4 DeviceCMYK
>
> **BG** *array (Optional):* An array of numbers that shall be in the range 0.0
> to 1.0 specifying the colour of the widget annotation’s background.
> The number of array elements shall determine the colour space, as
> described for BC.
>
> **CA** *text string (Optional; button fields only):* The
> widget annotation’s normal caption, which shall be displayed when it
> is not interacting with the user. Unlike the remaining entries listed
> in this Table, which apply only to widget annotations associated with
> pushbutton fields (see Pushbuttons in 12.7.4.2, “Button Fields”), the
> CA entry may be used with any type of button field, including check
> boxes (see Check Boxes in 12.7.4.2, “Button Fields”) and radio buttons
> (Radio Buttons in 12.7.4.2, “Button Fields”).
>
> **RC** *text string (Optional; pushbutton fields only):* The widget annotation’s rollover
> caption, which shall be displayed when the user rolls the cursor into
> its active area without pressing the mouse button.
>
> **AC** *text string (Optional; pushbutton fields only):* The widget annotation’s alternate
> (down) caption, which shall be displayed when the mouse button is
> pressed within its active area.

When you ask for the fill color, I assume that you're referring to the background color, which means you'll have to look at the **BC** entry for the colorspace, and at the **BG** entry for the actual color value.

Comment: I used dict.getAsDict(PdfName.MK).get(PdfName.BG) to get the color value, you mentioned table 189 to find out the specific attributes, Where I can find the table ? Is it in PDF spec?

Comment: Yes, and I copied it entirely in my answer: R, BC, BG, CA, RC and AC are the entries listed in that table. Suppose that BC is 3, than BG will be an array of three values: a red, green and yellow value expressed as a number between 0 and 1.

Comment: Thanks for clear explanation. Now I am able to read the color properties of acro fields. I updated my question. @BrunoLowagie