# Converting RGB values into color

Tags: java, colors, rgb

I have a java code that returns decimal values as shown below

```
 [1.0, 0.0, 0.0] for Red  
 [0.0, 1.0, 0.0] for Green
```

the first value denotes the color code for Red, the second value denotes color code for Green and the third value denotes Color code for Blue.

Is there any way we can convert these RGB values into the respective color in java?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for [this constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color%28float,%20float,%20float%29)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are an [example](http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.com/2011/12/java-reflection-getting-name-of-color.html) to return the color name which depend on using Reflection to get the name of the color (java.awt.Color)

```
public static String getNameReflection(Color colorParam) {
        try {
            //first read all fields in array
            Field[] field = Class.forName("java.awt.Color").getDeclaredFields();
            for (Field f : field) {
                String colorName = f.getName();
                Class<?> t = f.getType();
                if (t == java.awt.Color.class) {
                    Color defined = (Color) f.get(null);
                    if (defined.equals(colorParam)) {
                        System.out.println(colorName);
                        return colorName.toUpperCase();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error... " + e.toString());
        }
        return "NO_MATCH";
    }
```

and in the main

```
        Color colr = new Color(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        Main m = new Main();
        m.getNameReflection(colr);
    }
```

---

You have to know that :`"java.awt.Color"` defined this colors:

```
white
WHITE
lightGray
LIGHT_GRAY
gray
GRAY
darkGray
DARK_GRAY
black
BLACK
red
RED
pink
PINK
orange
ORANGE
yellow
YELLOW
green
GREEN
magenta
MAGENTA
cyan
CYAN
blue
BLUE
```

Comment: @MaheshVarma I was actually doing this answer in my pc now .. Coincidence

Comment: Nice to know that, a guy is working on the same requirement at the same time and at the same geographic location. @BharathRallapalli